# How make multiple files available as one, akin to symlinking?

Tags: files, filesystems, symlink, overlayfs, unionfs

Is there a way to take a list of files and make them available under a single name (in a read-only fashion)?

Let's say I have:

```
f1.txt
f2.txt
f3.txt
```

And I would like to read sequentially through all of them. For ease of file handling, I'd like to have a single (virtual) path, e.g. `virtual.txt` that behaves like a normal file and will contain the concatenation of `f1.txt`, `f2.txt` and `f3.txt`.

```bash
virtual.txt # symbolic, read-only view over f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt concatenated
```

In the [Go programming language](https://go.dev), there is something like that in the [io](https://pkg.go.dev/io) package, namely: [io.MultiReader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiReader):

> MultiReader returns a Reader that's the logical concatenation of the provided input readers. They're read sequentially. Once all inputs have returned EOF, Read will return EOF. If any of the readers return a non-nil, non-EOF error, Read will return that error.

Similar to an overlay filesystem, however - rather than passing through all files just exposing a single name.

Comment: You could get the same effect (minus the name) with the `bash`ism `<(cat f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt)`. Read `man bash`, search for the string "`<(`".

Comment: @waltinator - thanks, I knew about that bash feature.